# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment

Tags: java, spring, batch-file

I am getting the below error though the code is very simple:

```
2016-02-39 15:25:10 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:112 - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2016-02-39 15:25:10 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:107 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-02-39 15:25:10 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:107 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-02-39 15:25:10 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:116 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-02-39 15:25:10 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:503 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1ee0005: startup date [Mon Feb 08 15:25:10 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment(Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.deloitte.batch.client.PersonDaoClient.main(PersonDaoClient.java:28)
```

Code:

```
package com.anirban.batch.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.anirban.batch.dao.PersonDao;
import com.anirban.batch.domain.Person;

public class PersonDaoClient {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PersonDaoClient.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long personId=2;
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        PersonDao personDao = (PersonDao) ctx.getBean(PersonDao.class);

        Person person = personDao.getPersonById(personId); 
        System.out.println(person);
        System.out.println();

        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) personDao.getPersonList();
        for(Person p : personList){
          System.out.print(p.getPersonId()+"  ");
          System.out.print(p.getFirstName()+"  ");
          System.out.println(p.getLastName());
        }
        personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        personList.add(new Person("Abc", "Def"));
        personList.add(new Person("Ijk", "Lmn"));
        personList.add(new Person("Opq", "Rst"));

        personDao.save(personList);
    }
}
```

Dependencies as below:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-batch.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As I am working with spring batch there is some batch dependencies.
Can anyone please help. Probably I am missing something basic but cant find out.

Comment: you are not importing bean package

Comment: import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;                   import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;

Comment: Thanks @KVK. It's working now.

Comment: The main issue is the fact that you are mixing versions of spring, the import might "fix" it, but the real issue is still present. You are mixing 3.0.5 and 3.1.3 versions of Spring. Never mix jars from frameworks regardless the framework.

Comment: Yeah..Got it. For oxm if forgot to provide ${spring.version}. Thanks @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the bellow package

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
```